# Django Channels ORM Database Query

Tags: django, django-channels

I don't know what I did wrong

I can't get Database Data.

```py
class AsyncChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        users = await self.get_users()
        for user in users:
            print(user.id)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_users(self):
        return User.objects.all()
```

```
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

The information I checked and the official documents are all written in this way.

But why am I getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is duplicate on stackoverflow:

It's already explained there: [Django Channels Error: you cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232278/django-channels-error-you-cannot-use-asynctosync-in-the-same-thread-as-an-async)